# Worklight 6.2.0 - Mobile Browser Simulator will not open

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-mbs

I have a problem with the web emulator of worklight 6.2.0.

I have publicated an application with environment android and iphone, when i click in link "Preview as Common Resources" he it works perfect open the web page. But i click in android or iphone open the page with "Context Root Not Found"

Comment: Is this in the Eclipse plug-in (Worklight Studio), or in an external application server? Did you try in a few new workspace?

Comment: In the Eclipse plug-in!

Comment: Did you try with a new workspace and project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cannot confirm this.

- I've installed Eclipse Java EE 4.3.2 ("Kepler" SR2) + Worklight Studio from Eclipse Marketplace.
- Created a new project and application, and added the iPhone and Android environments
- Run As > Run on Worklight Development Server
- Previewing the iPhone and Android environment in Worklight Console successfully opened the Mobile Browser Simulator.

Try two additional things:

1. In Eclipse, delete the Worklight Development Server from the Servers view and restart
2. Close Eclipse, find your TMP folder and delete the wlBuildResources folder, then restart Eclipse

When the failure occurs, also check for errors in Eclipse > Console view > Worklight Development Server

Comment: I believe the problem occurred because the original project was in version 6.1. Excludes workpace and imported again aparti project now in version 6.2 and everything worked

Comment: @FábioDeCarli, Will you be willing to provide your project so that we will debug the issue?

Comment: @IdanAdan thi project is the company i work, i need the authorization. I will make a project to try to simulate to share, ok

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest that you switch to a new Workspace and allow the MobileFirst Studio to install a new Worklight Development Server.

Here are the steps to do so:

1. Create a new folder in your file system
2. Perform a Switch Workspace in Eclipse with the folder created from step 1.  In Eclipse, go to `File > Switch Workspace`.
3. Eclipse will restart and a new Worklight Development Server will be created automatically.
4. Import your project, then build and deploy to see if the issue still persists.